# COALESCE and IFNULL not working as expected

Tags: mysql, null

I'm trying to output a default row when there's no row found in the query. 
This is a sample of my query:

```
SELECT 
COALESCE(site, 'STE') as site, 
instrument,
field

FROM Table1
WHERE site IN ('East', 'West')
AND DATE(tstamp) = "2016-09-07"
ORDER BY id desc
```

The output is

```
+------+------------+-------+
| site | instrument | field |
+------+------------+-------+
| West | 0          | 0     |
+------+------------+-------+
```

For the tsamp 2016-09-07 we have a row for the site "West" and there's no row for "East". I tried to search and found that I can use COALESCE and also tried IFNULL but I'm only getting the output above. I also tried if(count(site) = 0, "STE", site) but i can't get it to work.

My expected result is

```
+------+------------+-------+
| site | instrument | field |
+------+------------+-------+
| West | 0          | 0     |
| STE  | NULL       | NULL  |
+------+------------+-------+
```

I hope you guys can help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your query has it `WHERE site IN ('East', 'West')` ... how would you expect to get a row where site has STE ? Unless you had a site=`NULL`

Comment: Is it STE or East? I have the impression the two are used interchangeably in your question...

Comment: its East. on Table1 for the date 2016-09-07 it doesn't have a row for the site East so i wanted it to just ouput a row that have the text/data 'STE' when there's no row available

Comment: *＋1* for keeping things on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Both coalesce() and ifnull() work on a row basis, meaning they can replace a null value if that null value exists in a record. However, they cannot create a record that does not exist - and you do not have any records matching East (or STE).

A possible solution is to create a table that has all possible values for the `site` field and you can left join on this table:

```
SELECT 
COALESCE(Table1.site, "STE") as site, 
Table1.instrument,
Table1.field

FROM LookupTable lt
LEFT JOIN Table1 ON lt.site=Table1.site
WHERE lt.site IN ('East', 'West')
AND DATE(Table1.tstamp) = "2016-09-07"
ORDER BY id desc
```

Comment: Hmm.. maybe i'm doing something wrong because its still not creating the 'null' / 'ste' row if the site doesn't exist.

Comment: it's still only outputting 

`West | 0          | 0     |`

Comment: And you expect me to figure out based on these 2 comments what you are still doing in a wrong way? Seriously?

Comment: sorry i didn't mean to offend. its just i did it the same way on your example and created another table that have all the possible values but its still only outputting the values that exist.

Comment: You need to update your question with all the steps you have done and the results you got. Otherwisewe cannot help you.

Answer (score 0):

If 'STE' isn't in table1.site then it won't come back in the results.

You could do a union instead:

```
SELECT 
site, 
instrument,
field

FROM (SELECT 'West' [Site], 0 [instrument], 0 [field]) table1
WHERE site IN ('East', 'West')
UNION 
SELECT 'STE', NULL, NULL
```

Note that by using "STE" you're looking for the column name "STE", not the value 'STE' (single quotes)

**EDIT**

You need a control table to dictate which values to look for, or you have to hard code your rules.  You can't look for something that's missing without first specifying the things that should be there.

Here's an option:

```
--Create and populate reference table "sites"
create table sites
    ([site] char (4))

INSERT INTO sites VALUES ('East')
INSERT INTO sites VALUES ('West')

-- Query against reference table
SELECT 
ISNULL(table1.site, 'STE'), 
instrument,
field
FROM (SELECT 'West' [Site], 0 [instrument], 0 [field]) table1
RIGHT JOIN sites on table1.[Site] = sites.[Site]

--or

-- Query against reference table
SELECT 
ISNULL(table1.site, 'STE'), 
instrument,
field
FROM sites
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 'West' [Site], 0 [instrument], 0 [field]) table1  on table1.[Site] = sites.[Site]
```

Let me know if you have questions on how this works.

Comment: wouldn't that always have the 'ste' row?, i only wanted to add that row if the row didn't exist

Comment: I'm getting syntax error: on the "FULL" line, 'FULL' is not a valid input at this location.

Comment: Oh, shouldn't it be FULL OUTER JOIN? i'll try it again

Comment: Changed it, gave right join/left join examples.  I didn't see that you're using mysql, which doesn't support full joins according to the internet community